# Add summary row to Pandas

Tags: pandas, summary

I am trying to summarise **sum** of rainfaill, but just add the **average** temperature :

```
data = [{'year':2020,'area': 'new-hills', 'rainfall': 100, 'temperature': 20}, 
    {'year':2021,'area': 'new-hills', 'rainfall': 110, 'temperature': 20},
    {'year':2019,'area': 'new-hills', 'rainfall': 111, 'temperature': 19},
     {'year':2020, 'area': 'cape-town',  'rainfall': 70, 'temperature': 25}, 
      {'year':2021,'area': 'cape-town',  'rainfall': 80, 'temperature': 23},
      {'year':2019,'area': 'cape-town',  'rainfall': 75, 'temperature': 24},
    {'year':2019, 'area': 'mumbai',  'rainfall': 200,  'temperature': 37 },
     {'year':2020, 'area': 'mumbai',  'rainfall': 170,  'temperature': 39 },
    {'year':2021, 'area': 'mumbai',  'rainfall': 180,  'temperature': 38 },
   ]
```

And this works, but I need to show the Average temp as well, but I don't know how to add it in and keep it on the **same** summary row.  This is just an example, but I need to use the identical arrangement on a real world project.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
container = []
for label, _df in df.groupby(['area']):
    _df.loc['summary'] = _df[['rainfall']].sum() # <-How do I add 2nd column that's not another 'sum' 
    container.append(_df)

df_summary = pd.concat(container)
df = (df_summary.fillna(''))
```

[image]

Example image of what I require (I've filled in the green values to show what I need the code to do).

Thankyou.

My code is on GitHub as jupyter notebook if you want to use that.
**[Pandas Summary Jupyter Notebook](https://github.com/RGGH/PDF-rename/blob/main/Pandas_Summary_Subtotals.ipynb)**

Comment: are you just looking for `.agg`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'year':2020,'area': 'new-hills', 'rainfall': 100, 'temperature': 20},
        {'year':2021,'area': 'new-hills', 'rainfall': 110, 'temperature': 20},
        {'year':2019,'area': 'new-hills', 'rainfall': 111, 'temperature': 19},
        {'year':2020, 'area': 'cape-town', 'rainfall': 70, 'temperature': 25},
        {'year':2021,'area': 'cape-town',  'rainfall': 80, 'temperature': 23},
        {'year':2019,'area': 'cape-town',  'rainfall': 75, 'temperature': 24},
        {'year':2019, 'area': 'mumbai',  'rainfall': 200,  'temperature': 37},
        {'year':2020, 'area': 'mumbai',  'rainfall': 170,  'temperature': 39},
        {'year':2021, 'area': 'mumbai',  'rainfall': 180,  'temperature': 38 }]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
container = []
for label, _df in df.groupby(['area']):
    _df.loc['summary'] = _df.agg({'rainfall': 'sum', 'temperature': 'mean'})
    container.append(_df)
df_summary = pd.concat(container)
df = (df_summary.fillna(''))

df
```

Output:

[image: pandas dataframe with summary rows]

#### EDIT

Following the subsequent request to replace the temperature average by a constant, here is the modified code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'year': 2020, 'area': 'new-hills', 'rainfall': 100, 'temperature': 20},
        {'year': 2021, 'area': 'new-hills', 'rainfall': 110, 'temperature': 20},
        {'year': 2019, 'area': 'new-hills', 'rainfall': 111, 'temperature': 19},
        {'year': 2020, 'area': 'cape-town', 'rainfall': 70, 'temperature': 25},
        {'year': 2021, 'area': 'cape-town', 'rainfall': 80, 'temperature': 23},
        {'year': 2019, 'area': 'cape-town', 'rainfall': 75, 'temperature': 24},
        {'year': 2019, 'area': 'mumbai', 'rainfall': 200, 'temperature': 37},
        {'year': 2020, 'area': 'mumbai', 'rainfall': 170, 'temperature': 39},
        {'year': 2021, 'area': 'mumbai', 'rainfall': 180, 'temperature': 38}]

my_constants = [10, 20, 30]

def map_constant(x, v):
    x.mean()
    return v

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
container = []
for i, group in enumerate(df.groupby(['area'])):
    label, _df = group
    _df.loc['summary'] = _df.agg({'rainfall': 'sum', 'temperature': (lambda x: map_constant(x, my_constants[i]))})
    container.append(_df)
df_summary = pd.concat(container)
df = (df_summary.fillna(''))

df
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is helpful. Ideally I need to place one "SUM" value, and one Fixed value on my summary row.  Is it possible to modify   df.loc['summary'] = _df[['rainfall']].sum()  so that I have the SUM value below "rainfall" and constant value bleow "temperature" .  *I'm not so great at merge/join.concatenate when combined within a summary...

Comment: One SUM value, and one fixed value (I'll be gathering the fixed value from elsewhere within the code)

Comment: Could you provide an example with the data above?

Comment: Ok, so on my screenshot, where I've drawn in values in green, in the rectangles, is it possible to add in my own values, so the summary line shows: the SUM of the rainfall, and a value in the "tempertature" column that is supplied by my code (and NOT from SUM/AVERAGE/MEAN)   (I'll be calculating the actual values elsewhere)

Comment: The summary rows will now contain the constants listed in `my_constants` under `temperature`.